# First order homogeneous differential equations: comparison between two results

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, differential, chemistry

The differential equation to solve is the following

$$ -\dfrac{dc_\mathrm{B}}{dt} = k_1\ c_\mathrm{A,0}\ e^{-k_1 t} - k_2\ c_\mathrm{B}$$

This formula expresses the variation in B $(dc_\mathrm{B})$ concentration as a function of time, where $k_1, k_2$ and
$c_\mathrm{A,0}$ are constant.

Applying the solution formula

$$c_\mathrm{B} = e^{-\int k_2\ dt} \left[ \left( \int e^{\int k_2\ dt} \times k_1\ c_\mathrm{A,0}\ e^{-k_1 t} \right) + \mathrm{const.} \right]$$

And applying the initial condition

$$c_\mathrm{B}(0) = 0 \rightarrow \mathrm{const.} = \dfrac{k_1\ c_\mathrm{A,0}}{-k_2-k_1}$$

What I get is

$$c_\mathrm{B} = \dfrac{k_1\ c_\mathrm{A,0}}{-k_2-k_1} e^{(k_2-k_1)t}$$

[Detailed steps to get my result](https://i.imgur.com/Yfvre0k.jpg)

The solution (without steps) shown in the teacher's slides is

$$ c_\mathrm{B} = k_1\ c_\mathrm{A,0} \left( \dfrac{e^{-k_1t}}{k_2-k_1} + \dfrac{e^{-k_2t}}{k_1-k_2} \right) $$

Are these two solutions the same solution written differently? Or am I the one who did something wrong?

Comment: $e^{(-a+b)}$? By the way, is my result right?

Comment: Are you absolutely ***sure*** of *all* signs in your original ODE?

Comment: @CosmasZachos nope, there's a mistake in the original sign ODE. I solved my problem: I post my solution as soon I can